# Spring won't instantiate and I keep getting this infinite loop

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, loops, infinite

I'm trying to find out what have I done wrong. It would be great if anyone could help me. I keep getting this in an infinite loop:

```html
May 02, 2015 9:41:57 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@799f7e29: startup date [Sat May 02 21:41:57 EEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
May 02, 2015 9:41:57 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
May 02, 2015 9:41:57 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@548a9f61: startup date [Sat May 02 21:41:57 EEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
May 02, 2015 9:41:57 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
```

UsersDAOImp :

```html
public class UsersDAOImp extends GenericEntityDAO implements UsersDAO   {
 
 
 private SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) BeanManager.getBean("sessionFactory");

 public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
  return sessionFactory;
 }

 public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
  this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
 }
 
 public List<Users> selectAll() {
  Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
  session.beginTransaction();
  Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Users.class);
  
  List<Users> users = (List<Users>) criteria.list();
  session.getTransaction().commit();
  return users;
 }
}
```

UsersService

```html
public class UsersService {
 
 UsersDAOImp usersDAO = new UsersDAOImp();
 
 public void setUsersDAO(UsersDAOImp usersDAO) {
  this.usersDAO = usersDAO;
 }
 
 public UsersDAOImp getUsersDAO() {
  return usersDAO;
 }

 public List<Users> getAllUsers() {
  return getUsersDAO().selectAll();
 }
}
```

Bean manager used to get context
    public class BeanManager {

```
/* BeanManager is used to parse Beans.xml file */
private static ApplicationContext context;

private BeanManager() {
}

public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
    return context;
}

public static void setContext(ApplicationContext context) {
    BeanManager.context = context;
}

public static Object getBean(String beanId) {
    if (context == null) {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
    }
    Object result = context.getBean(beanId);
    return result;
}
```

}

This is my Beans.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

 <bean id="usersDAO" class="com.survey.persistance.DAO.UsersDAOImp" />
 <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app" />
  <property name="username" value="" />
  <property name="password" value="" />
 </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Where is your xml file ? Can you paste a screenshot of your project structure?

Comment: http://s17.postimg.org/iyisf2qdb/Untitled.png

Comment: Please move your Beans.xml to resources folder and use it as source folder ( right click on folder - Build Path - Use as source folder)

Comment: Why UserDAOImp is not using dependency injection and retrieving session factory from a static class? That is wrong.

Comment: My project went through a series of refactorings and this is it's final form for UserDAOImp (Using DI) http://s16.postimg.org/ychduy23p/new_User_Dao_Imp.png

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?